# Represent number N (N>1) as N = x + y, where x * y is the maximum possible value

Tags: c#, algorithm

My problem is the following: I have to find such x and y (x+y=N) where x * y is the maximum possible value.

I have written an algorithm (which I think works well) and I am looking for more efficient and faster way to solve this problem.

This is my algorithm:

```
static void Find(int N)
{
    int multiplication = 1;
    int maxMultiplication = 1;
    int desiredNumber = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= N / 2; i++)
    {
        multiplication = i * (N - i);
        if(multiplication > maxMultiplication)
        {
            maxMultiplication = multiplication;
            desiredNumber = i;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Desired presentation of number N is --> N = {0} + {1}",
        desiredNumber, N - desiredNumber);
}
```

Comment: Do you know any differential calculus?

Comment: I have done some courses. I think I will be able to understand the explanation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} x(N-x) = N - 2x$$
At a maximum, \$\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} = 0\$, so the maximum occurs when \$x = \frac{N}{2}\$. (Left as an exercise: show that it's a maximum and not a minimum).

Therefore you can skip the loop: `desiredNumber = N / 2;` is all you need. Note that if `N` is odd this gives the pair \$\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \right\rfloor, \left\lceil \frac{N}{2} \right\rceil\$, which is the correct solution in integers.

Comment: If N is odd then n/2 + n/s != n.  A better generalization is n/2, n - n/s.  OP is using integer math.

Comment: @paparazzo, what's `s`? And if that should say `2`, where are we in disagreement?

Comment: Yes 2.   In integer math 25/2 = 12  so I think need 12, 13

Comment: And where are we in disagreement? `desiredNumber` will be assigned `12`.

Comment: I up-voted.  Not going to argue.   12 + 12 != 25.   You specifically give the pair as n/2, n/2.

Comment: @paparazzo I missed the MathJax at first as well: the stated pair is `floor(N/2), ceil(N/2)`, which will give `12, 13` for `N=25` (and otherwise equivalent to your suggestion of `floor(N/2), N-floor(N/2)`)